# What the line numbers in hexdump means?

Tags: hex

I tried to find some explanation in internet about what the line numbers in hexdump means and why they are ordered 00000000, 00000010, 00000020 and not 1,2..a..a2 etc. but it was unsuccessful. Can some one help me understand this one?

Comment: because 1 in the next column is a power of 16

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "line numbers" are actually byte offsets at the beginning of each line, represented in hex notation.

Since there are 16 bytes per line, and the first line starts with byte #0, the offsets are:

```
00000000
00000010 (which means 16 in decimal)
00000020 (which means 32 in decimal)
... etc
```